# How do I verify data consistency between two non-relational databases?

Tags: mongodb

I looked up a lot of information, but I'm still not sure how to verify data consistency（or migrate databases better）.  Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

I  have an old database A, and new database B,  I need to migrate part of A's data to B（about a terabyte）. When I change A to B without affecting the service, I should make sure that some of the data states that are currently running are consistent with either "success" or "pending", and don't lose data.

I have a dual write scheme that inserts and updates the database at the same time，and copy part A data to B，When data is consistent between two databases, switch traffic to B.

1. Is there a better migration database solution？
2. Is there a small tool for verifying data consistency between two non-relational database？

   How do I verify data consistency between two non-relational databases（or migrate databases better）？

   For the first time to ask questions here. Thank you very much.

Comment: This shouldn't be a [tag:python] question, it should be a [tag:mongodb] question. You'd probably set up some database-to-database replication, and once your data is replicated you switch over to the new primary. Also see http://dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Yes, it is a question about MongoDB, thanks for correcting.